# How do I implement a ServiceKnownType helper class in a pcl assembly

Tags: c#, wcf, portable-class-library

I have a servicecontract declared in PCL assembly that I'd like to hook up to a serviceknowntype helper class.

Typically, I'd a add a [ServiceKnownType("GetTypes", typeof(HelperClass))] attribute to the class. This works, but I can't implement HelperClass in the pcl assembly, as System.Reflection.ICustomAttributeProvider is not available.

Is there a way to workaround this without having to list every type I need?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem? I have just hit that wall

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible.

If the PCL references Windows Phone 8.1 the WCF classes are unavailable. Part of those are the ServiceKnownTypeAttribute.

It is (apparently) a well known bug in Windows Phone 8.1 (not Windows Phone Silverligt 8/8.1, it works there) that Microsoft, because of time issues did not have time to implement the WCF in Windows Phone 8.1.

It is implemented in Windows (Phone) 10 as it is available in PCL's that target Windows 10 Universal.